# python 3 syntax issue with "import queue " - TypeError and calling object correctly

Tags: python-3.x

Still learning python but need some assistance. I am attempting to convert this python 2.x code to use with 3.6. 
https://github.com/dentedbrain/arubaPythonCode/blob/master/Aruba_Conf/csv_conf.py

I changed the usual stuff like print(), etc but I can't figure out how to correct these queue lines in the code. I did change the import Queue to "import queue" but I can't resolve this next error when I run the script. I can't figure out how to define/call the Object correctly. ??

```
    working_queue = queue() 
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Python3, you should instantiate Queue this way:

```
from queue import Queue
working_queue = Queue()
```

Be careful with the case of the first letters...

Comment: Geez I promise you I already did that or maybe I had it swapped. IT works now!

I'm not familiar with using this queue class. Do you have any idea how the queued_host gets the ip?  That part doesn't seem to work on py3 now after change the it from Queue to queue.  Just curious.

Comment: @MarcosXuma I recommend you to ask that in a new question, since it is not related to what has been told here. That's how it works here in SO.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Thank you!